# Can't right-click a context menu strip c#

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu

I have a "hidden" c# windows form that runs in the tray. I've added a ContextMenuStrip control to it and up until last night it worked fine, but now right-clicking it does nothing. The icon appears in the tray but like I said right-clicking it does nothing. I tried adding a second contextMenuStrip but that doesn't work either. I right-click the icon and nothing happens. I tried putting breakpoints in my code inside the associated methods and they never get hit. What could be wrong? I even went back to an older version of the code and that's not working either. I've tried on two different computers - the laptop I developed this on and my desktop at home.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Answer (score -1):

It was simple. Delete the NotifyIcon and ContextMenuStrip and then re-add them. Now it works fine.